# Assigning pointers to arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I want to do something like this below:

```
int main() {
   int a[10];
   int *d = generateArrayOfSize(10) // This generates an array of size 10 on the heap
   a = d;
   print(a); // Prints the first 10 elements of array.
}
```

However above code gives compilation error (incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [10]’). 
What can I do to make the above code to work?

Comment: As the designer of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup, [says](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#arrays), an array is "a very low level data structure with a vast potential for misuse and errors and in essentially all cases there are better alternatives". Try using an STL container.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are non-assignable and non-copyable, so you'd have to copy each element by hand (in a loop), or using `std::copy`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using C++, then use C++ arrays rather than C style arrays and pointers. Here's an example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
std::array<int, N> generateArrayOfSize(void)
{
    std::array<int, N> a;
    for (int n=0; n<N; ++n)
        a[n] = n;
    return a;
}

template<size_t N>
void print(std::array<int, N> const &a)
{
    for (auto num : a)
        std::cout << num << " ";
}

int main() {
   std::array<int, 10> a;
   std::array<int, 10> d = generateArrayOfSize<10>();
   a = d;
   print(a); // Prints the first 10 elements of array.
}
```

which outputs `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Answer (score 3):

**Arrays are not pointers.**

You can't do :

```
int a[10];
int *d;
a = d;
```

Change it to :

```
int *a;
int *d;
a = d;
```

Main differences between arrays and pointers in C programming :

```
Pointer                                    | Array
-------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------
A pointer is a place in memory that keeps  | An array is a single, pre allocated chunk
address of another place inside            | of contiguous elements (all of the same
                                           | type), fixed in size and location.
-------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------
A pointer can point to a dynamically       | They are static in nature. Once memory is 
allocated memory. In this case, the memory | allocated , it cannot be resized or freed
allocation can be resized or freed later.  | dynamically.
-------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------
```

You have a quite good explanation here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725410/1394283

Comment: I actually find the list of differences more confusing than helpful. *Pointer can’t be initialized at definition.* => of course they can: `int a = 3; int* b = &a;`, *The memory allocation can be resized or freed later* => not a characteristic of the pointers, but of *some* pointed-to memory. *The assembly code of Pointer is different than Array* => this does not mean anything to a beginner to start with.

Comment: Agree. `Pointer can’t be initialized at definition.`  Downvoting for that alone.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I removed the parts who were not clear. But I meant that the memory pointed-to by the pointer cannot be initialized during the pointer definition...

Comment: The second point raised by @MatthieuM. still applies. In fact, a pointer could point to an array, which, as you say, cannot be resized or freed.

Comment: @TomBlodget I tried to make it more clear... It's quite hard to explain this idea in few lines. But thanks to point out that it is not exact.

Answer (score 2):

An array is **not** a pointer (although a name of an array often decays to a pointer to its first element).

To make the above code to work, you can declare `a` as a pointer: `int *a;`. The `print` function takes an `int*` (or a decayed array) anyway.

If you really want to have two arrays and copy contents from one array to another, you should copy the data in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will print in this way when you assign a string reference to a pointer you have to use *ptr to print the value of a pointer otherwise in your case **print(d)** that is like cout< in c++ it will only print the location of the d[0].

```
 int ary[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
 int *d;
 d=ary;
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 cout<<*(d+i);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, it was always true when Thing X[10]; was declared, X was the constant address of the first element(i.e. &X[0]).  So you could then say:

Thing *Y = X;  // Equivalent to (Thing *Y = &X[0];)

But in C++, the compiler "remembers" that the Thing array X has 10 elements, and some C++ imposed type checking rules break.  Imagine we add Thing Z[20]; to the discussion.

Thing *Y = X; and Thing *Y = Z; if both allowed, would imply that a single variable could be set to Thing Arrays of length 10 and 20, which are very different (ahem) "things", as a quick look at a 2D array will reveal. This sort of justifies why the C language assumed equivalent of X and &X[0] is broken in C++.

Well, at least for some versions of C++.  So best not to assume it, and use
Thing *Y = &x[0]; and Thing *Y = &Z[0] instead;

This approach has two advantages.  It does what is wanted, and it actually compiles. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because array names are non-modifiable. So you can't do

```
a = d;
```

Declare it as a pointer like this:

```
int *a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Little rusty with my C++ but try something like this.

```
int main() {
   int *a;
   int *d = generateArrayOfSize(10) // This generates an array of size 10 on the heap
   a = d;
   print(a); // Prints the first 10 elements of array.
}
```