# Confused about Pointers to Pointers and Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am having a difficult time fully understanding what is going on.

This is how I am reading the code at the bottom.

1. Define A as a pointer to an address of a pointer that points to
   address of a double.
2. Allocate 4 blocks of memory on the heap that can each hold an
   address to a double. Return the address of the first block allocated
   to A.
3. Allocate 6 blocks of memory on the heap that can each hold a double
   data type and return the first block's address for each of the 4
   blocks allocated earlier.
4. Variable A still contains the address of the first block of the four
   pointers assuming that A[0] changed the value at the address pointed
   by A rather than A itself.

Now this is where the diagram comes in that is linked at the bottom. Lets say that I wanted to access the data stored in the red block. How would I do so?

Would the following code work?

```
double data = *(*(A + 3) + 2);
```

My logic is that A is a pointer and incrementing by 3 should increase the address by the number of bytes that is of the size (double *). Dereferencing the address (A + 3), I would obtain the address of first block (assuming it was not re-assigned). By increasing the resulting address by 2 and dereferencing that address, I should obtain the value at the red block.

So if I understand correctly, 1 + M pointers are being stored in memory. Why? If the goal is to store MxN data, why would I need 1 + M pointers to do so? The extra pointers seem like they would be helpful if I wanted to define rows of different sizes but the objective is to define a rectangular array of data.

```
const int M = 4;
const int N = 6;
double **A;

A = malloc(M*sizeof(double *));

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    A[i]= malloc(N*sizeof(double));
}
```

Diagram:

[image]

Side Note:
I am Electrical Engineering student that is unfamiliar with C to some degree and formal programming practices. I know that I'm being pedantic about the such a simple line of code, but I want to be sure that I understand pointers and memory allocation correctly. They are pretty hard to comprehend at first glance. This is part of a matrix multiplication code given to me by my professor and I want to pass the pointer to a function and have it access and modify the correct values in memory. Personally would of liked to see two-dimensional arrays for this code, but I am assuming that there is a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can also store this contiguously and just do the math instead of letting the compiler do it for you

So:

```
double * A = malloc (M * N * sizeof(double));

double get(double * what, cur_x, cur_y, max_x, max_y)
{
    return *(what+cur_x*max_y+cur_y);
}
```

this will save all the indirection since you know the size

If you don't need to allocate sizes dynamically this is what

`double A[17][14]` will do for you on the stack

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `double data = *(*(A + 3) + 2);` would work, and access the "red" double.

I guess your professor will tell you soon that `A[3][2]` works as well, is much easier to read, and preferable to `*(*(A + 3) + 2);`

Lesson learned (not yet, but what your professor is trying to teach to you): in C, multidimensional arrays are *not* something like 'a table with N columns and M rows', in C, all arrays are really pointers, and multidimensional arrays are implemented as pointers to pointers. Whenever your write `A[3][2]`, `*(*(A + 3) + 2)`is what really happens internally. This, in turn, explains why you can't allocate a N*M matrix in one statement; you have to allocate the "row pointers" first, then allocate the "columns" for each of the row pointer.

Comment: *"C, all arrays are really pointers"* No. Arrays will decay into pointers and array-subscripts work for pointers but they are [not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725008/pointers-difference-between-array-and-pointer). *"you can't allocate a N*M matrix in one statement"* yes you can: `double A[M][N];`, though for big matrices you don't want to allocate it on the stack. Using VLA's you can use `double (*A)[N] = malloc(M * sizeof *A);` though.

Comment: I think I just epimone, what I was talking about in the main post is a linked list right? All array are linked lists?

Comment: No, an array is a block of memory that may be addressed contigously: `int arr[10] = {...};` then you can access `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` up to `arr[9]`. Those statements are equivalent to: `*(&arr[0] + 0)`, `*(&arr[0] + 1)` etc. (`&arr[0]` is the address of the first element, had I written `*(arr + 1)` it would go 1 past the end of the array, you could also do: `int * ptr = arr;` and then use `*(ptr + 0)`, `*(ptr + 1)` due to array-to-pointer decay). The double-pointer looks like a linked-list but unlike a true LL there is no (other) data in the pointer itself except the address it points to.

Comment: @Altermeris Correction to my last comment: `*(arr + 1)` is equivalent to `*(&arr[0] + 1)` so taking the address of the first element is not necessary. I don't know why I thought otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc(M*sizeof(double *))` says: "Give me a pointer to *M* double pointers."
`malloc(N*sizeof(double))` says: "Give me a pointer to *N* doubles."
Now notice the bug:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    A[i]= ...;
}
```

`A` points to an array of *M* double pointers, but you are writing *N* entries into it (where each entry is a pointer to *N* doubles). If `M > N` you waste space, and if `M < N` you use space that you haven't asked permission to write to.