# Is *s equivalent to s[i]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

On page 106 of K&R C, in `strcmp` function, it takes pointers `*s` and `*t` as arguments but in the `for` loop, it specifies

```
s[i]==t[i]
```

as a condition.

Just want to confirm, for arrays, as

```
*(s+i) and s[i]
```

are synonymous, hence, can the function statement use `s[i]` instead of `*s`?

Comment: I think you're misrepresenting the function: It doesn't take "pointers `*s` and `*t`", rather, it takes pointers `s` and `t`.

Comment: A simple search for the `[]` poerator would have answered this. Before asking a question, try to solve to yourself. And how should `*s` be the same as `s[i]` (unless `i` is zero)?

Comment: Yes it's true that for any valid pointer *or array* `s` and index `i` the expression `*(s + i)` is equal to `s[i]`. That means that `*s` is equal to `s[i]` ***only*** if `i` is zero (`*s` is the same as `*(s + 0)` which is the same as `s[0]`).

Comment: Yes, *(s+i) and s[i] are equivalent.

Comment: This is the reason why `3["abcde"]` is a valid expression which evalutes to `'d'`.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Gerhardh, now that we know that `s[i]` is equal to `*(s + i)` we need to remember that addition is [*commutative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) which means that `*(s + i)` is equal to `*(i + s)` which then is equal to `i[s]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers - Difference between Array and Pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725008/pointers-difference-between-array-and-pointer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postﬁx expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   deﬁnition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Thus

`a[i]` is equivalent to `*( a + i )` and in turn is equivalent to `i[a]`

For example

```
int a[1] = { 10 };

printf( "a[0] == *( a + 0 ) is %s\n", a[0] == *( a + 0 ) ? "true" : "false" );
printf( "a[0] == 0[a] is %s\n", a[0] == 0[a] ? "true" : "false" );
```